# Difference between cmake variables and cmake arguments

Tags: c++, ubuntu, cmake

I have been given some source code, along with a `CMakeLists.txt` file, and told to run cmake by:

```
cmake ../src -DOPEN_NI_ROOT=/home/karnivaurus/OpenNI
```

I have also noticed that there is a file called `FindOpenNI.cmake`, which I believe is used when `find_package(OpenNI)` is called by cmake.

Therefore, I am guessing that `OPEN_NI_ROOT` is some kind of variable that is used by cmake for the remainder of setup.

However, I have tried inserting the line `set(OPEN_NI_ROOT "/home/karnivaurus/OpenNI")` into my `CMakeLists.txt` file, in an attempt to avoid the need to add it as an argument at the command line. But this does not seem to do the same thing.

Can somebody please explain how these two variable types are different?

---

The file `FindOpenNI.cmake` is open source and can be found at:
https://github.com/victorprad/InfiniTAM/blob/master/InfiniTAM/cmake/FindOpenNI.cmake

Comment: Does this `FindOpenNI.cmake` happen to be open source? If it is, it'll help a lot if you could link it here.

Comment: Yes -- see my updated question....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is this line in `FindOpenNI.cmake` ([link](https://github.com/victorprad/InfiniTAM/blob/61837dafa020572776f39bada9cb83a324111945/InfiniTAM/cmake/FindOpenNI.cmake#L9)):

```
set(OPEN_NI_ROOT "/usr/local" CACHE FILEPATH "Root directory of OpenNI2")
```

This will set `OPEN_NI_ROOT` unless it's already in the cache. A simple call to:

```
set(OPEN_NI_ROOT "/home/karnivaurus/OpenNI")
```

does not set the variable in the cache, so it will be overridden when the line in `FindOpenNI.cmake` is hit. Using the command line form of setting the variable *will* set it in the cache, which is why it works just fine.

The easiest way to avoid having to set the command line option is to set the cache explicitly in your own `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set(OPEN_NI_ROOT "/home/karnivaurus/OpenNI" CACHE FILEPATH "Root directory of OpenNI2")
```

If you're working from a dirty build directory, it's likely this cache variable already exists, so this line would have no effect. In that case, either work from a clean build directory, or set the `FORCE` option:

```
set(OPEN_NI_ROOT "/home/karnivaurus/OpenNI" CACHE FILEPATH "Root directory of OpenNI2" FORCE)
```

This will write over the cached value. Note that this would prevent you from setting the option in the command line in the future, which is why this method isn't preferred. You can find some more information about the mechanics of this [here](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/set.html).

Comment: Yes, that works thanks. I also had to be sure to include this definition in my `CMakeLists.txt` file before using the `add_subdirectory()` command, otherwise the variable is not registered.